# users getting prompted for login for site content when they are a member of the subsite

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

sharepoint 2019 on-premise

Structure is as follows. Broken inheritance. 
Site
   Subsite-A
   Subsite-B

If a user is in the members group for a Subsite and tries to open the Site Contents they get prompted for a password again which fails and they have to re-log into the site.

The user has read only to the Main site.

The only fix was to make the user a Member of the main Site and then it all worked.

What is in the parent site that could be causing this?

Is there a way so that users that do not need to modify the parent site data can have read-only to the parent and still have member access to a subsite?

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Enable automatic logon with current username and password in IE.

To enable automatic logon with current user name and password, go to Internet Explorer->navigate to Settings -> Internet Options->On the Security tab, click Custom Level->Under User Authentication, select Automatic logon with current user name and password.

2. Add the site into trusted site in IE.
3. Go to subsite-A->site settings->site permissions->Delete unique permissions->Stop Inheriting permissions->re-grant the permission to the User in the subsite and check if the same issue will occur.
4. Create a new subsite, break inheritance and add the user into the subsite to check if the same issue will occur.

Comment: i did try that but same results. Tried with Edge, Firefox and IE (with that setting).  Sorry for the late response, i did not realize I replied to your answer with an answer instead of a comment so the post was deleted.